# How to spawn two processes with proc_open at the same time?

Tags: php, proc-open

```
<?php
$ds=array(1 => array("pipe", "w"));
$ds1=array(1 => array("pipe", "w"));
proc_open("notepad.exe", $ds, $pipes);
proc_open("notepad.exe", $ds1, $pipes);
?>
```

I just want to create two notepad.exe processes at a time, but the second processes was not created, until the first notepad.exe was killed.
How to create multiprocess at a time ?

Comment: Have you tried using `start notepad.exe`? But you won't be able to wait until it stops though

Comment: Please accept an answer if it answers your question. I see that you have asked 7 questions, including 6 upon which you received an answer for, but you never accepted even one as an answer to your question. It is the least you can do when someboy takes the trouble to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

as Jack suggests you can use start to start a process and forget about it; if your application win run under unix - [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/pcntl_fork) can help you to create multiple threads - and from them spwan multiple processes.